# jquery document ready fails when url contains '#'

Tags: javascript, url, hash, onload

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
});
```

or

```
window.onload = function () {
}
```

doesn't triggers when URL contents '#' character at end. Any idea to get through?

example: http://beta.something.com/user.php#

javascript onload never trigger on above url. how can i get it triggered?

Comment: This should be something other than the hash. Do you have a live example?

Comment: Simply not true. There must be more to your problem. Here's an example of a URL with a hash in it: http://www.klevensudde.com/sv/projektet/#imageslide The jQuery loads just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Without further information it's hard to be sure, but I suspect you're *already* on the same page, so going to a "hashed" url won't actually reload the page and the onload function won't fire.

In other words, if on the page user.php you have a link like this: `<a href="user.php#">foo</a>`, clicking on it won't reload the page but just moves you to the top of the document and no onload event is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

The ready and load events are only triggered when the page is first loaded. When you go to the same page with a bookmark added to the URL, the page is not reloaded, the browser just scrolls to the bookmark in the page.

An URL ending with just a hash character has an empty bookmark, so the browser scrolls to the top of the page.